# Can the real projective plane extended to a 3 space by R partition R4?

Tags: general-topology

I know $\mathbb{R}P^2$ immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ self-intersects: Roman surface, Boy surface. Is there an embedding of $\mathbb{R}P^2\otimes\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that partitions it, analogous to a sphere partitioning $\mathbb{R}^3$ into an inside and an outside? I don’t see how you could do that with a non-orientable surface, but I don’t know what the embeddings look like.

Comment: Intuitively, wouldn't you expect to need a $3$-dimensional "surface" in order to partition a $4$-dimensional space?

Comment: Of course - see below.

Comment: So is there any 3-dimensional manifold that is partitioned by an embedding of a non-orientable 2D manifold in its interior? I suspect not, because one can "cross" the surface to a nearby point "on the other side" just by traversing the surface.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by the tensor product of ${\mathbb R}P^2$ and ${\mathbb R}$, this is a nonstandard notation. Do you simply mean the direct product?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do that with any sort of $2$-dimensional manifold, orientable or no. Magic words are: Alexander duality.

Comment: I should’ve been clearer. Partition is the wrong word. Either like a circle in R3 can separate it into a disk and it’s compliment. Or alternatively, a partition by RP2xR.

Comment: @brian the first question is what I was answering. For the second question the answer is still "Alexander duality".